# get html result of php in html file

Tags: javascript, php, html

This code will send request to post parameters to php file:

```
var param = //some parameters;
var url = file.php;
xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhttp.send(params);
```

I got the response but the php file produce some output like `<td><tr>.....`
How to get this result of php in some div of my html?

Thanks,

Comment: Google... this has thousands of answers.

Comment: I did not find answer

Comment: I cant use jQuery. I am working on client side.

Comment: >.< Just include the jquery CDN file in the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `onreadystatechange` to get the response:

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) { 
        $('#mydiv').html(xhttp.responseText);
    }
};
```

Comment: @Reem if you're getting the response why isn't that in your question? You need to include all relevant code! I've updated my answer to put the code into a div with an ID of `mydiv`

Answer (score 0):

XHR is pretty complicated without using a Framework. Just use jQuery it will make this 1000x easier.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "myfile.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    /* Params */  
  },
  success: function(response){
    /* Use your response here */  
  }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I am working on client side. I cannot use jQuery because the server turn off $ by $.noConflict();

Comment: you can use `jQuery.ajax` instead of `$.ajax`

Comment: And that makes 0 since jQuery is for the client side only.

Comment: what is jQuery.ajax? I know there is jQuery and there is ajax. can you show me an example? I am new to this concepts.

Comment: jQuery is a library, it contains an function called AJAX. please just click the link i provided

Comment: I know what you mean but, when I include jQuery library in my html I got an error in my platform. When I delete the library, the platform is running!

Comment: Use a better platform. Use almost any other platform ever and it will work. I suggest Apache